# Why am I not able to open a VS project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio project that I created in my previous PC (32-bit if that makes any difference). I recently got a new PC (64-bit) and I am trying to open the project and I am seeing the following error:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - ONew, "C:\temp\onb\ONewSln\ONew\ONew.csproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio without changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.
     - ONewWeb, "C:\temp\onb\ONewSln\ONewWeb\ONewWeb.csproj"
     - ONewSln, "C:\temp\onb\ONewSln\ONewSln.sln"
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Is there a add-on or visual studio component that I have to download to make it work?

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research and spending hours banging my head against the wall, I figured out how to resolve the issue.

You have to install Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012.

Open up the Web Platform Installer and if you don’t have it installed, [download](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and install it. Search for Office Developer Tools and install it.

This will enable you to open the project without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can open VS2010 SP1 files in VS2012. But after opening and on compiling you may get some errors of missing packages. Then you have to install the missing packages. Check this out: [Visual Studio 2012 compatibilty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747(VS.110).aspx).

> Some solutions, projects, files, and other assets that you created in Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1) will run without modification in Visual Studio 2012, but others have to be upgraded. The above document describes how various kinds of assets behave in these two versions of Visual Studio.
>
> If you use both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1, you can create and modify projects and files in either version as long as you don't add features that require Visual Studio 2012.

VS2012 may convert projects when you first open them, but the changes are (except noted in the document linked) backward compatible with VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Am I downloading something to my PC?

Comment: Sorry didn't got you. Please clarify.

Comment: From your response, I am just confused. Am I downloading something to my PC to enabled me to open the project?

Comment: no need to download anything unless vs asks for it.

Comment: I can't build it before i open the solution?

Comment: Is it a vs 2010 solution?

Comment: They are both built with 2012. I am using TFS

Comment: The project target is v4.5 .net. I checked my PC version by going here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP` and I didn't see a folder for v4.5. So I downloaded the .net 4.5 framework and went to install it. I got the following message: `Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer.` I am confused because I did not see an entry for v4.5